# API call does not display photos

Tags: javascript, api

I am building an app to display all representatives in a riding. I cannot seem to get the pictures to display. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to call the url like so:

```
const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = `http://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/K2H6G7/${representatives_centroid.photo_url}`
```

This doesn't provide me with the errors I was getting before but the photos don't display.

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.response);
data.representatives_centroid.forEach(representatives_centroid => {
    const card = document.createElement('div');
    card.setAttribute('class', 'card');


    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = `http://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/K2H6G7/${representatives_centroid.photo_url}`

    const p1 = document.createElement('p');
    p1.textContent = `${representatives_centroid.party_name} ${representatives_centroid.elected_office} ${representatives_centroid.first_name} ${representatives_centroid.last_name}`

    const p2 = document.createElement('p');

    p2.textContent = `${representatives_centroid.district_name}`

    container.appendChild(card);

    card.appendChild(img);

    card.appendChild(p1);                
    card.appendChild(p2);
});
```

Comment: What happens when you console log `representatives_centroid.photo_url` ?

Comment: If all you can tell us is "they don't display", then you don't seem to have debugged this at all? Do you know how to use your browser's Develoer Tools (including element inspector, console and network tool)? Log the photo URL variable's value. Then inspect the final generated HTML and see if it is constructed how you expected, and that the image URLs are correct. Also watch your Network tools while this code is running - when you append an image you should see it make HTTP requests to the URL in the "src" tag. Again you can see if the URL is ok, and you can see what response is coming back.

Comment: we have no idea what photo URLs you are feeding into the code, or whether they point to anything real, so it's hard to help. That's why you need to check your data first. P.S. If you show us the content of `this.response` Then we could actually run this code and help you a lot more easily. Or we might just be able to predict what's going wrong by looking at the data and seeing how the code will use it.

Comment: @gugateider my apologies. I am using the following API: 

https://represent.opennorth.ca/postcodes/K2H6G7/?format=apibrowser

Comment: @ADyson I will spend sometime digging for more information. I did not know how to use the developer tools properly so I appreciate the thorough response.

Comment: based on the API you don't need to concatenate your URL 'represent.north...' as the `photo_url` is already an absolute path to the correct image. Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: @gugateider You are correct. I did not need to concatenate. The photos appear now. Thank you very much.